# Finite second homotopy group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am interested in sufficient conditions for the second homotopy group $\pi_2(X)$ of a compact connected manifold to be finite. Are there familiar classes of manifolds $X$, for which this is the case?

Comment: Lie groups all have trivial $\pi_2$.

Comment: Simply connected manifolds with finite $H_2(X;\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: This is a condition on the universal cover, and so three large classes of manifolds with this property are the flat, hyperbolic, and (except when $n=2$) spherical manifolds, whose universal covers even all have trivial $\pi_2$.

Comment: Are you aware that any finite dimensional connected CW-complex has the homotopy type of a compact connected manifold? Your question is too broad.

Comment: Yes, the problem is broad. Therefore I am not asking for necessary and sufficient conditions and that is also why I am writing about "familiar classes of manifolds" which fulfill the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have for instance a look at the following paper

*Manuel Amann and Anand Dessai*, MR 2600123 [**The $\hat A$-genus of $S^1$-manifolds with finite second homotopy group**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.crma.2010.01.011), *C. R. Math. Acad. Sci. Paris* **348** (2010), no. 5-6, 283--285.

and at the references given therein.